# Fireworks CS6: easy way to adjust values like in Photoshop?

Tags: cs6, adobe-fireworks

In Photoshop we can easily increase/decrease any values by using arrow keys or dragging left/right after hovering mouse on the subject. But I found neither is possible in Fireworks CS6. Am I missing something?

Comment: You just type the value you want. For some reason, Adobe didn't implement this the same way as other tools, but when you get used to how much more productive you'll be with digital graphics in FW, you honestly won't miss it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean values such as border radius and stroke?
Or values such as brush size?
Or both?

There are countless amounts of useful extensions that may be able to help, such as these http://fireworks.abeall.com/extensions/

Comment: Great idea. I will definitely check out the extensions

Comment: Sadly I can't find any. Someone has a clue?

Comment: Ps and Fw are built on 2 different platforms so this may have something to do with it. However, this extension http://fireworks.abeall.com/extensions/#Brush allows you to set keyboard shortcuts to increasing and decreasing the brush size. Like in Ps, ']' will increase brush size, and '[' will decrease.

Comment: I think he's talking about alphanumeric text input fields that double as some sort of drop down. I'm not sure what the name would be. But in photoshop, and many applications, if you're focussed on one, you can arrow up or down to select through possible options.